# Restlet add parameter to webservice call

Tags: java, web-services, rest, parameters, restlet

I cannot seem to find anything on the subject on the site of restlet or anywhere on how to add parameters to a webservice call.

I am able to use restlet to call a webservice that doesn't need any parameters and handle the respond.

If you know any other frameworks that are able to call a webservice and pass parameters(rest) please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To add a query parameter to a webservice call with Restlet (version 2.3) you can do the following:

```
// Create a client resource which will call a given service
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("http://serviceToCall.com");

// Add a query parameter
clientResource.addQueryParameter("queryParameterName", "queryParameterValue");

// Make a "GET"
clientResource.get();
```

Here is the corresponding [Javadocs](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/jee/api/org/restlet/resource/ClientResource.html#addQueryParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. Based on the example from [the Restlet wiki](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/320-restlet.html):

```
// Create the client resource  
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("http://www.restlet.org");  

// Add a query parameter equiv to ?A=1
resource.getReference().addQueryParameter("A","1"); 

// Customize the referrer property  
resource.setReferrerRef("http://www.mysite.org");  

// Write the response entity on the console
resource.get().write(System.out);
```